# Are SSHDs with SATA transparent to operating system/mother board?

Tags: drivers, hard-drive, ssd, hardware, sshd

I was trying to find answer to this question for many days.

What my current laptop has:

> 500GB Serial ATA drive

What I want to replace with:

> Seagate SSHD SATA drive

Does this change require any additional drivers/mother board up gradation? Or since the interface (SATA) is same in both cases, it is going to be transparent or atleast work?

**Device information:**

Laptop: Sony VAIO (E Series)

Laptop-model: [VPCEH3AEN](http://www.sony.co.in/support/product/VPCEH3AEN)

Current hard drive: Seagate [ST9500325AS](http://www.seagate.com/staticfiles/support/disc/manuals/notebook/momentus/5400.6%20(Wyatt)/100528359e.pdf)(0007SDM2)

Current hard drive part number: 9HH134-500

Comment: What is your model and manufacturer of your laptop?? I am not sure but someone else can use this info to give you a answer.Reply in comments.

Answer (score 1):

I have a `Seagate 1TB 5400RPM 64MB SATA 9,5MM Laptop Thin SSHD 8GB Flash, ST1000LM014` in my Samsung laptop, works perfectly and the speed up is noticeable.

In theory this kind of disks should be perfectly equivalent to a normal disk at least at the basic "it works" level (it can create problems in seek optimization, but this is not in my experience).

There are some report around of problems with some [Samsung disks](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fstrim/+bug/1449005), but my experience with the Seagate has been completely positive.

Comment: So, it almost always works in a laptop which is compatible with SATA?

Comment: So, it almost always works in a laptop which is compatible with SATA? What I could not find on Internet is if the whole NAND thing is transparent to mother board and I can safely buy SSHD SATA hard disk.

Comment: In principle, it *should* be so. I have only one data point with my seagate disk tough.